# How to set up connection to FeathresJS server from Expo (react-native) app that use MobX

Tags: expo, feathersjs

Is there any Expo-Feathers-MobX boilerplate? All I can find is boilerplates and projects based on react-native-cli which I couldn't get them to work on my machine.

I'm trying to use FeathersJS server socket as my back-end server for my Expo app but I could not get it to connect. It's hard to sum all the attempts that I tried so I'm asking for a boilerplate, a guide or a tutorial please.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just use the REST API provided by FeathersJS? Or your project requires a client?

Comment: I need socket for real-time changes

Comment: Hello. Some progress with this? Try this example here: https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-socket-io

Comment: Thank you. I gave up feathers and switched to Meteor and all backend pain gone